# Download image from url and store it as a file

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to download the image from this URL.

> https://t0.rbxcdn.com/8d05159c75d0f5f7c8068bc928bb1a12

I want to use it as a texture so it would have to be stored as a file in the app.
I will be changing the image on the server so thats why I am trying to do it this way.

This is what I have so far.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageUrlString = "https://t0.rbxcdn.com/8d05159c75d0f5f7c8068bc928bb1a12"
    let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString)!

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

        let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:200, height:200))
        imageView.center = self.view.center

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        }
    }
}
```

The script allows me to see the image but I am not sure how to save it as a file.

Comment: `imageData.write(to: URL)`

Answer (score 0):

You can image into your document directory

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory(tempImage:UIImage){

let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("texture.png")
    do {
        try UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage)?.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        }
}
```

You can you retrieve image from document directory using below function

```
func getTextre()->UIImage?{

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
 let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("texture.png")

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL)
}else{
    return nil
    }
}
```

"texture.png" is sample name, you may keep it whatever you want.

Comment: I get an error when trying to retrieve the image. At the line for "    return UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL)" I get this error, " Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String' "